# Best approach to create inverse data for logistic regression 'predict variable (desired target)

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression, feature-extraction

I'm trying to think of a quick way to create 'inverse' for the purpose of training a logistic regression model.
I've got sales transactions (i.e *isSold=1*) and I want to  create the data rows for the *isSold=0* equivalent for the 2nd date (as obliviously I dont have the data for that)... Using the example below, 
I'd need to create 4 new rows for 'ABC1','DEF2','GHI3','JKL4' with the below (NOTE that MNO5 isn't required as there is already data available for 2/2/20).

```
students = [ ('ABC1', '1/1/20', '5.00' , '2' , '1') ,
             ('DEF2', '1/1/20', '4.95' , '1' , '1' ) ,
             ('GHI3', '1/1/20', '6.50' , '1' , '1' ) ,
             ('JKL4', '1/1/20', '7.10' , '1' , '1' ) ,
             ('MNO5', '1/1/20', '8.45' , '2' , '1') ,
             ('MNO5', '2/1/20', '8.45' , '1' , '1')  ]


df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = ['Item' , 'Date', 'UnitPrice' ,'Quantity', 'isSold'], index=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'])
```

Any/ all ideas are welcome - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after sleeping on it I came up with the below....

```
dts = ['1/1/20','2/1/20']
codes = ['ABC1','DEF2','GHI3','JKL4','MNO5']

for i in codes:
    for j in dts:
        new_row = {
          "Item": i ,  
          "Date": j,
          "UnitPrice": 0,
          "Quantity": 0,
          "isSold": 0
        }
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Item','Date'], keep='first')
```

Any improvements or feedback are welcomed!